# What URL should I use for local host callback using Apache webserver?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, spotify

I'm trying to create an application using the spotify API on Laravel and using the Apache webserver, what URL should I use for the redirect URL? http://localhost:8888/callback is not working and comes back with an invalid address.

Thanks!

I tried http://localhost:8888/callback, changing and viewing the ports but nothing, also googled extensively but haven't found anything that solves my problem.

Comment: What exactly do you need to specify, a _redirect_ URL, or a _callback_ URL? You can use local addresses for the former (because that is for a redirect that makes the _client_ request this URL), but not with the latter (because that is a URL that Spotify's servers will try to make a request to, and that of course can not work with a localhost URL.)

Comment: @CBroe A redirect URL, which in the spotify docs can be used with a localhost. I've found the port number apache is runnig on which is port 80 but using that local host URL brings me a 404, not sure what URL to use that would work with Apache?

Comment: You have to _create_ that endpoint yourself, so how can you be "not sure" which URL it _should_ be?

Comment: @CBroe yea I'm sorry mate this is all new to me haha, I just saw that using a localhost it seemed putting that and the port I'm using should be enough. So I need to create a callback URL in my routes folder then I'm assuming?

Comment: @macrol5 — Yes. Spotify has to send you data. You need to be ready to receive it. The URL you give to Spotify tells them where to send it to get it back to you.